# Delete blank rows from table, error when there are no blank rows to delete

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to write a code which deletes any blank rows within my table after a data dump has been dropped and refresh the workbook. This works fine except for when there isn't any blank rows:

```
Range("Table3").Activate
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Any ideas on how to get round this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
Sub kjhdfuvhx()
Range("Table3").Activate
On Error Resume Next
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```